# Coderunner IDE auto-indent?

Tags: ide, auto-indent, coderunner

Using the Codeblocks IDE there is an option "Format use AStyle" to auto-indent my entire C++ code. I can't seem to find an option like this in Coderunner V2 for Mac and the web is pulling up nothing. Does anyone know if this option exists?

Comment: I'm looking for the same feature. I'm emailing the author now.